# Login script that requires user to re-enter displayed random number string

Tags: bash, scripting, login

I currently have a script that runs upon a user logging into a Linux server and at the end it prints

```
[Terms of use agreement prints here]

read -p "Agree and continue..." -nl -s
```

However, most users I find are just "entering" through the prompt (spacebar, enter, random keys, etc) since the script isn't looking for specific entry, and now users have written their own scripts or macros to enter past this.

As a solution, I would like the script to print a string of random numbers, and then require the user to enter those numbers back into the prompt before allowing access.

Example:

"Welcome to Server! Please enter the following one-time passphrase to continue: 1234.

Key: "

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is necessary to use **read -p**? Otherwise you can do the following (this would be a proof of concept script):

```
#!/bin/bash
RANDOMNUM=$(shuf -i 0000-9999 -n 1)
echo "Introduce password $RANDOMNUM"
read value
if [ $value == $RANDOMNUM ];
then
        echo "Password Match!"
else
        exit
fi
```

**Shuf** would create a random number of 4 digits between 0000 and 9999.

Comment: Using read -p is not necessary, it was only being used because I found that solution online previously. I'll give this a shot, thanks!

Comment: Do you know how I could enable the script to execute exit if the numbers are incorrect, or if a non-4 digit numeric entry is provided?

Comment: You have to only add an else to the if as any value that does not match with the condition will be threated as "else". I have modified my previous script to include the else and the exit values.